# How often can I / should I restart my new Tor relay?

Tags: relays

To my current understanding, the longer the Tor relay operates continuously, the better.

But what if I want to do some maintenance on the server? I don't want to lose the newly given Guard flag (status). Currently the relay operates a week straight.

**Question:**
With regard that it is a completely new relay, should I run at least those 68 days straight before I do the first maintenance tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restart it for sure - once a day is no problem! I've tried to run it many days straight and with restarts - same result in flags. And it's a *correct* flagging behaviour : the relays must not be penaltized for restarting, because a patch-tasks are in order in a real and safe operational schedule. My relay's restart lasts 2 minutes with full system reboot, and it have not affected a flags.